# How do I update a list data_relation in Python Eve

Tags: python, eve, datarelation

I have a model 'users' and a schema for it, which includes a one-to-many relation back to users:

```
'followers': {
    'type': 'list',
    'schema': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'data_relation': {
                    'resource': 'users'
            }
    }
},
```

I am trying to update the list of followers. I tried sending PATCH request to the **/users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1** endpoint with a 'followers' key and a list of objectids but it doesn't work. Also tried sending a PUT request to **/users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1/followers/** but no luck.

So how do I add an object to this list with Python Eve REST API?

```
GET /users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1/
{
    "_updated": "Fri, 07 Nov 2014 08:07:40 GMT",
    "public_key": "test",
    "_etag": "256d6da738a0f39929d40d1c868e1f67661460be",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1",
            "title": "User"
        },
        "parent": {
            "href": "",
            "title": "home"
        },
        "collection": {
            "href": "/users",
            "title": "users"
        }
    },
    "active": false,
    "_created": "Fri, 07 Nov 2014 08:07:40 GMT",
    "_id": "545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1"
}

PATCH /users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "message": "You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.",
        "code": 403
    }
}

PUT /users/545c7dccb505970bbf0e5ad1/followers
{
    "_status": "ERR",
    "_error": {
        "message": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
        "code": 404
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doesn't work` is awfully broad... however at a guess you need to send your `_etag` token the server returned when fetching or creating the user... this is required to prevent updating from an out of date model

Comment: Where does the server return the _netid token? Is this a header of some sort? I don't see it in the JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to add "If-Match" header to the request and put the _etag value there.

Comment: Also, Eve docs have a section devoted to [concurrency and data integrity control](http://python-eve.org/features#data-integrity-and-concurrency-control) too. You were getting `422 Precondition Failed` with your response (a detail worth posting in your question by the way), precisely because the ETag was missing in your request.