# How to add to a list type in Python Eve without replacing old values

Tags: python, rest, eve

I have a very similar setup to the person in this question:
[How do I update a list data_relation in Python Eve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811438/how-do-i-update-a-list-data-relation-in-python-eve)
with a users resource and a friends sub-resource of list type.

```
users = {
    …
    ‘friends’: {
    'type': 'list’, 
        'schema': {
        'type': 'objectid’, 
        'data_relation': { 
            'resource': 'users’ 
        } 
    }
 }
},
```

However, when I try to add a new value to the friends list, the other values in the list get replaced by the new value. How do I add a single value to the list and keep the old values?

```
GET /users/5522987f893e3902048c55ff

{
"_updated": "Wed, 15 Apr 2015 17:22:07 GMT",
"_created": "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 14:30:23 GMT",
"_id": "5522987f893e3902048c55ff",
"friends": [
    "552e9eb0893e391063045edc"
]
}

PATCH /users/5522987f893e3902048c55ff
{"friends": [“550f288d893e390204b0a5ac”]}

RESPONSE:
{
"_updated": "Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:38:06 GMT",
"_created": "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 14:30:23 GMT",
"_status": "OK",
"_id": "5522987f893e3902048c55ff"
}

GET /users/5522987f893e3902048c55ff

{
"_updated": "Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:38:06 GMT",
"_created": "Mon, 06 Apr 2015 14:30:23 GMT",
"_id": "5522987f893e3902048c55ff",
"friends": [
    "550f288d893e390204b0a5ac"
]
}
```

I have also tried PUT, but it replaces the list with the new value as well.

***EDIT:***
I just tried using POST.

```
POST /users/5522987f893e3902048c55ff/friends
{"552e9eb0893e391063045edc"}

RESPONSE:
{
"_status": "ERR",
"_error": {
    "message": "The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.",
    "code": 404
}
}
```

AND

```
POST /users/5522987f893e3902048c55ff
{"friends": ["552e9eb0893e391063045edc"]}

RESPONSE:
{
"_status": "ERR",
"_error": {
    "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.",
    "code": 405
}
}
```

Comment: You should use a POST to add a new element ...

Comment: Never use MS Word to edit you programs or data. You have some ellipses and quotes that are autocorrected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just edited my question after I tried posting a new friend.

Comment: @AmyEubanks I have the same problem. How did you resolve this since it's not natively supported in eve.

Comment: @CraigH I just posted my workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST will allow you to add a new document to the `users` endpoint. If it is returning a 405 then you most likely need to enable the POST method by adding it to the `RESOURCE_METHODS` list, as all endpoints are read-only by default; see [docs](http://python-eve.org/config#global-configuration) (alternatively you can only enable POST for the individual endpoint by adding the method to the local `resource_methods` instead.)

PATCH allows for the replacing of individual fields (as opposed to PUT, which will replace the whole document). So with PATCH you can atomically update the `friends` list by *replacing* it with a new value (a new list ObjectIds in your case), but you cannot push a single new ObjectId inside the existing list, I am afraid.

Comment: I am able to POST to 'users', just not to a single 'users/<id>'. I see that it is not allowed, because I get a ConfigException from Eve when I add it to the 'ITEM_METHODS' list. I'll use PATCH like you say and keep track of old values. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Is there any plan to support the `push-to-list-field` operation in Eve?

Comment: @nicola, is there a way to append on the list documents.

Comment: Haven't yet figured a way to allow it in a proper RESTful way, to be honest.

Comment: So does that mean if i want to add objectIds into a list, inside a resource, the only way is keep resending PATCHs as the list keeps growing? I.e., in my client i have to cache each instance?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround that I used. It's probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it worked for me.

Instead of having a `users/friends` list like I had originally planned, I ended up creating a resource for `shares.` In my case, I wanted to know which `crystals` were shared with which `users.` So when I query `crystals/<crystal_id>/shares,` I should get a list of the `shares` for that `crystal.`

I think you could apply a solution like this to the `users/friends` scenario if you swap `crystals` for `users` and `shares` for `friends.` You might put two different `user_id` data_relations in your `friends_schema` (my `shares_schema`).

```
shares_schema = {
    'crystal_id': {
        'type': 'objectid',
        'required': True,
        'data_relation': {
            'resource': 'crystals',
            'embeddable': True,
        },
    },
    'user_id': {
        'type': 'objectid',
        'required': True,
        'data_relation': {
            'resource': 'users',
            'embeddable': True,
        },
    },
}

shares = {
    'internal_resource': True,
    'schema': shares_schema,
}

crystals_shares = {
    'schema': shares_schema,
    'url': 'crystals/<regex("[a-f0-9]{24}"):crystal_id>/shares',
    'datasource': {'source': 'shares'},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reply with my solution, I hope it will be useful after so long...
You don't really need a specific implementation in eve to update lists, it can be easily solved using hooks:
In resource where the relation points, define a  Database event hook on_update (prior to insert):

```
app.on_update_users += update_users
```

Define the function as follows:

```
def update_users(updates, original):
    if 'friends' in original:
        if 'friends' in updates:
            updates['friends'] = list(set(updates['friends'] + original['friends']))
    return True
```

patching:

```
curl -X PATCH -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://127.0.0.1/users/63a12c8795e8ef7a4617823e' --data '{"friends":["63a12c8795e8ef7a4617823f"]}'
```

After the patch you will have the new element in the friends list and the previous ones will not have been deleted (if they exist).